# Mobx Store shows lag in nested input range. Causes slow performance

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx, mobx-react

I have a simple MobX store with `padding` & `padding2`, the difference is one is an object:

```
import { observable, action, makeObservable } from "mobx"

export type Padding2 = {
    horizontal: number
    vertical: number
}

export interface IStore {
    padding: number
    updatePadding({ padding }: { padding: number }): void
    padding2: Padding2
    updatePadding2({ horizontal, vertical }: Partial<Padding2>): void
}

export class Store implements IStore {
    padding = 100
    padding2 = {
        horizontal: 100,
        vertical: 50,
    }

    constructor() {
        makeObservable(this, {
            padding: observable,
            updatePadding: action.bound,
            padding2: observable,
            updatePadding2: action.bound,
        })
    }

    updatePadding({ padding }: { padding: number }) {
        this.padding = padding
    }

    updatePadding2({ horizontal, vertical }: Partial<Padding2>) {
        if (horizontal) this.padding2.horizontal = horizontal
        if (vertical) this.padding2.vertical = vertical
    }
}

export const store = new Store()
```

And I have a simple `<input type="range" />` like:

```
import * as React from "react"
import { observer } from "mobx-react"

import "./styles.css"
import { useStore } from "./context"

const App = () => {
    const store = useStore()
    const { padding, updatePadding, padding2, updatePadding2 } = store

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>MobX Slow Perf for Range</h1>
            <h2>Padding</h2>
            <input
                type="range"
                name="padding"
                value={padding}
                onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                    const padding = Number(e.target.value)
                    updatePadding({
                        padding,
                    })
                }}
            />
            <span>{padding} px</span>

            <h2>Padding2</h2>
            <input
                type="range"
                name="horizontal"
                value={padding2.horizontal}
                onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                    const horizontal = Number(e.target.value)
                    updatePadding2({
                        horizontal,
                    })
                }}
            />
            <span>{padding2.horizontal} px</span>
        </div>
    )
}

export default observer(App)
```

When I use the slider on `padding` (the 1st slider) it goes from `100` to `0` smoothly but when I do it on `padding2` (the 2nd slider) it shows noticeable lag.

[image: mobx slow perf]

Here's a minimal Codesandbox → https://codesandbox.io/s/mobx-range-slow-perf-3zobu?file=/src/App.tsx

How do I solve it without using another local state like `React.useState()` for `padding2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subtle bug here is that `updatePadding` checks if `horizontal` or `vertical` are [**truthy**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). This means that the value of 0 returns false, and the store isn't updated at all then. As a result, when you quickly drag it left, the slider jumps to 0 but its value isn't updated.

To fix this, you'll want to explicitly check if they're `undefined`

```
updatePadding2({ horizontal, vertical }: Partial<Padding2>) {
  if (horizontal !== undefined) this.padding2.horizontal = horizontal;
  if (vertical !== undefined) this.padding2.vertical = vertical;
}
```

Comment: Damn I never would've catched it. Thank you so much :)